# Is $\zeta(2n+1)\notin (2\pi)^{2n+1}\mathbb{Q}$ already known?

Tags: reference-request, irrational-numbers, riemann-zeta, conjectures, rationality-testing

Is it already shown or at least conjectured that $$\zeta(2n+1)\notin (2\pi)^{2n+1}\mathbb{Q}?$$

You have any names and years who proved or conjectured it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [Apery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_theorem) (i.e. the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$) indicates $\zeta(2n+1)/(2\pi)^{2n+1}$ has been conjectured to be not merely irrational but transcendent. To this end they cite the following paper:

> Kohnen, Winfried (1989). "Transcendence conjectures about periods of
>   modular forms and rational structures on spaces of modular forms".
>   *Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. Math. Sci.* **99** (3): 231–233. (This is available online through Springer [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02864395), but access is paywalled.)
>
> Abstract: The conjecture is made that the rational structures on spaces of modular forms coming from the rationality of Fourier coefficients and the rationality of periods are not compatible. A consequence would be that $\zeta(2k-1)/π^{2k-1}$ ($\zeta(s)$=Riemann zeta function;$k\in\mathbb{N}$,$k\geq2$) is irrational or even transcendental.

Comment: I should hasten to add: I don't claim that this paper of Kohnen is the source of the conjecture; the purpose of that note is simply to place it within a certain context re: modular forms. The conjectures themselves are likely far older.